# Gradle plugin download dependency programmatically

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

curently I am writing a gradle plugin and I need to add and download a maven dependency programmatically in a given task.

I evaluated `DependencyHandler` and `ArtifactResolutionQuery` but I can't figure out where and how to add a Dependency and resolve it in mavenCentral repository

Similar coding for Maven does look rather easy

```java
Artifact artifact = artifactFactory.createArtifactWithClassifier(groupId, artifactId, version, type, classifier);
      
artifactResolver.resolve(artifact, remoteRepositories, localRepository);
```

So I guess/hope there is a similar easy way in Gradle and I am just not seeing it

Regards
Mathias

Update 1:

So here is some of the stuff I tried, wildly c&p from different tries. it is worth saying that the dependency I want to download has the classifier ZIP, so normal in my `build.gradle` I write

```groovy
  compile 'group:artifact:version@zip
```

to get the file

```java
ComponentIdentifier componentIdentifier = new DefaultModuleComponentIdentifier("com.sap.cloud",
                "neo-java-web-sdk", "3.39.10");

System.out.println("CompIdentifier = " + componentIdentifier.getDisplayName());
//getProject().getDependencies().add("compile", componentIdentifier.getDisplayName());


Configuration configuration = getProject().getConfigurations().getByName("compile");
org.gradle.api.artifacts.Dependency dep2 = new DefaultExternalModuleDependency("com.sap.cloud", "neo-java-web-sdk", "3.39.10");

boolean depList = configuration.getDependencies().add(dep2);
//
configuration.forEach(file -> {
    getProject().getLogger().lifecycle("Found project dependency @ " + file.getAbsolutePath());
});
Set<File> files =  configuration.resolve();
for (File file2 : files) {
    System.out.println("Files: " + file2.getName());
}

DependencyHandler dep =  getProject().getDependencies();
ComponentModuleMetadataHandler modules = dep.getModules();

ArtifactResolutionQuery a = getProject().getDependencies().createArtifactResolutionQuery()
   
 .forComponents(componentIdentifier).withArtifacts(MavenModule.class, SourcesArtifact.class);
ArtifactResolutionResult r = a.execute();
Set<ComponentArtifactsResult> set = r.getResolvedComponents();
Set<ComponentResult> c = r.getComponents();
```

Comment: How about the example for the [`ArtifactResolutionQuery`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.query.ArtifactResolutionQuery.html)?

Comment: @lu.koerfer updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way to download a dependency programmatically in a Gradle plugin is the same as doing it in a build script. Just create a new configuration, add your dependency and resolve the configuration. Watch the example below how this works in Java (the preferred language for Gradle plugins):

```java
Configuration config = project.getConfigurations().create("download");
config.setTransitive(false); // if required
project.getDependencies().add(config.getName(), "com.sap.cloud:neo-java-web-sdk:3.39.10@zip");
File file = config.getSingleFile();
```

For this example, the name of the configuration (`"download"`) can be **any string** not already used as configuration name (like `compile` or `runtime`). Since the configuration will be resolved afterwards, you must use another name whenever you reuse this code snippet (or if you call it multiple times).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it out tommorow. What does the line create(download) do exactly?

Comment: It creates a new configuration with the name `download`. As I tried to explain in the answer, you can simply change it to something else.

Comment: In my own plugin, I find it useful to search for, and if missing, create a configuration where I add sane default dependencies.

Comment: I think it is better to replace `project.getConfigurations().create("download")` with `project.getConfigurations().detachedConfiguration(<dependencies>)` as adding this auxiliary configuration to `ConfigurationContainer` is an undesired side effect.